# How to not re-render a child component when a parent's state changes in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component that is visible or hidden depending on its parent's state. How can I prevent the child from re-rendering when the parent's state changes? I've tried using memo but it's not working.

For example, if I make the child visible, then show "Text1", then hide the child, and then make it visible again, I want "Text1" to still be showing.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useCallback, memo, useMemo } from "react";
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  }, []);

  const MyComponentMemoized = React.memo(MyComponent);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{open ? "Close div" : "Open div"}</button>
      {open && <MyComponentMemoized />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyComponent.js

```
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [showText1, setShowText1] = useState(false);
  const [showText2, setShowText2] = useState(false);
  const [showText3, setShowText3] = useState(false);

  const handleShowText1 = () => {
    setShowText1(!showText1);
  };

  const handleShowText2 = () => {
    setShowText2(!showText2);
  };

  const handleShowText3 = () => {
    setShowText3(!showText3);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Hello there
      <button onClick={handleShowText1}>Show text 1</button>
      {showText1 && <div>Text 1!</div>}
      <button onClick={handleShowText2}>Show text 2</button>
      {showText2 && <div>Text 2!</div>}
      <button onClick={handleShowText3}>Show text 3</button>
      {showText3 && <div>Text 3!</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(MyComponent);
```

Here is a link to [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-browser-6629tk?file=/src/components/MyComponent.js)

Also, I'd like to avoid using a state management system to solve it, I'm interested in not re-rendering the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `open` state to the child:

```js
<MyComponentMemoized open={open} />
```

And inside the child component you can return null if the state is set to false:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ open }) => {
  ...
  
  if (!open) return null;

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```